# How to download much files in a loop in node js?

Tags: node.js

i take a first steps with **node.js** and i don't understand async code.
I would to make a code who **downloads 1k files from links**.
In my code i used package **"node-downloader-helper"**.
and this package work to one or 2 files.
when loop is bigger **downloads max 70 files and all don't working correctly**
all are downloaded incorrectly.
Its my code:

```
 let uniq = [array with 1000 links];

   async.forEachOf(uniq, function (value, key, callback) {
        const dl = new DownloaderHelper(value, 'E:/XAMPP/htdocs/mydownloads/pdf/',{fileName: key+".pdf"});
        dl.on('end', () => console.log('Download Completed'))
        dl.start();
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err.message);
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2syW.png)

**solution**

```
const save =  async (link, index) => {
    const dl = new DownloaderHelper(link, linkToDirectory)

    await dl.start();       
}

const forLoop = async _ => {
    console.log('Start')

    for (let index = 0; index < uniq.length; index++) {
      const link = uniq[index]
      const response = await save(link, index)
      console.log(response)
    }

    console.log('End')
  }

  forLoop();
```

Comment: the downloads are probably interrupted because the file size is not correct, but I don't know why